# Python SQLite - fuse_hidden not deleted

Tags: python, sqlite, fuse

I am trying to setup a python script to get some data and store it into a SQLite database. However when I am running the script a .fuse_hidden file is created.

On windows no .fuse_hidden file is observed but on ubuntu it generates at each call. The .fuse_hidden file seems to contain some form of sql query with input and tables.

I can delete the files without error during runtime but they are not deleted automatically. I make sure to end my connection to the db when I am finished with the query.
lsof give no information.

I am out of ideas on what to try next to get the files removed automatically. Any suggestions?

## Testing

In order to confirm that it is nothing wrong with the code I made a simple script
(Assume there is an empty error.db)

```
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect("error.db")
cur = conn.cursor()

create_query = """
CREATE TABLE Errors (
    name    TEXT
);"""

try:
    cur.execute(create_query)
except:
    pass

cur.execute("INSERT INTO Errors (name) VALUES(?)", ["Test2"])
conn.commit()
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

Comment: Does the python script close the connection to the database correctly?

Comment: Yes, I establish a connection to the db, execute the query and then call cursor.close() and connection.close()

Comment: @snakecharmerb Created a small test code that generates the same .fuse_hidden files.